# Drawing Shadowed Rectangle at iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing

I am trying to draw an image like below with libraries in iOS; but i couldn't.

[image]

I think it is very easy to draw but i couldn't achieve. 
After i accomplish to draw i will place a label over it.

Comment: I am not sure which is suitable for me. I will place a label on it, so i may be view i think.

Comment: Draw it by code with CoreGraphics. It's much more flexible -- you can change colors, shadow radius, offset at will, and you won't need separate 1x and 2x versions.

Comment: Can PaintCode demo help me? I need a tutorial, because i don't know so much about CoreGraphics ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as your `drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect

    //// General Declarations
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Shadow Declarations
    UIColor* shadow = [UIColor blackColor];
    CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    CGFloat shadowBlurRadius = 2;

    //// Frames
    CGRect frame = rect;

    //// Abstracted Graphic Attributes
    CGRect shadowBoxRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0, 40, 40);
    CGFloat shadowBoxCornerRadius = 4;


    //// ShadowBox Drawing
    UIBezierPath* shadowBoxPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: shadowBoxRect cornerRadius: shadowBoxCornerRadius];
    [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill];
    [shadowBoxPath fill];

    ////// ShadowBox Inner Shadow
    CGRect shadowBoxBorderRect = CGRectInset([shadowBoxPath bounds], -shadowBlurRadius, -shadowBlurRadius);
    shadowBoxBorderRect = CGRectOffset(shadowBoxBorderRect, -shadowOffset.width, -shadowOffset.height);
    shadowBoxBorderRect = CGRectInset(CGRectUnion(shadowBoxBorderRect, [shadowBoxPath bounds]), -1, -1);

    UIBezierPath* shadowBoxNegativePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: shadowBoxBorderRect];
    [shadowBoxNegativePath appendPath: shadowBoxPath];
    shadowBoxNegativePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    {
        CGFloat xOffset = shadowOffset.width + round(shadowBoxBorderRect.size.width);
        CGFloat yOffset = shadowOffset.height;
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context,
            CGSizeMake(xOffset + copysign(0.1, xOffset), yOffset + copysign(0.1, yOffset)),
            shadowBlurRadius,
            shadow.CGColor);

        [shadowBoxPath addClip];
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-round(shadowBoxBorderRect.size.width), 0);
        [shadowBoxNegativePath applyTransform: transform];
        [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
        [shadowBoxNegativePath fill];
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, i need to modify height and width but it works perfectly.

Comment: ;) So, actually i had to accept @Cyrille's answer but i can't :)

Answer (score 1):

Inner shadows are hard to do with CoreGraphics -- basically, you need to negate your path and draw a drop shadow below it, clipped to your original path.

You can take a look at [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) and it will show you the code. It has a 15-min demo mode if you don't want to purchase it, that should be enough for your needs.

Comment: this app is very good, i think it will always help me for further drawing problems ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and in your code , after making the your view  set these:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = x;

self.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
```

This allows you to have rounded corners on your view. And if you calculate the radius to match your view , you should get the desired look.

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
         self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }
        return self;
    }
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 
           CGContextRef context =UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            // And draw with a blue fill color
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);


            CGContextAddRect(context, self.bounds);

            CGContextStrokePath(context);


            // Close the path
            CGContextClosePath(context);
            // Fill & stroke the path
            CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width/12;
            self.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;

}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: here is the result of this code http://d.pr/i/q0rl . I created a new View (with .h and .m files) and modify .m file with code above. After that i insterted a view to my ViewController and set View's class that i created before.

Comment: Yes. I think that is your required diagram. Did you have any any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code where `myView` is the `UIView` to which you want to set the shadow.

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius   =   5.0f;
myView.layer.masksToBounds  =   YES;
[myView.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.5]];
[myView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: 3rd and 4th lines gives following error. No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'setShadowColor:'